# How to make my application to open the url when clicking the Alt button

Tags: javascript

I want to create my web application is more friendly to use. so I created a new functionalities like of if am want to move my page from current window to some other url, I am planing to press the 'ALT' Key.

I can able to get that functionality in my chrome as well as IE(11), the thing is its working properly in chrome and in IE, When keypress the page is going to the target but along with that the Browser Menus are also gets trigger.

How to control this browser behaviour

any my code is

```
 $(function () {
        var sar = false;
        // Need to cancel event (only applies to IE)
        if ( "onhelp" in window ) {
            // (jQuery cannot bind "onhelp" event)
            window.onhelp = function () {
                return false;
            };
        }
        $(document).keydown(function ( evt ) {
            // Alt pressed
            if ( evt.keyCode === 18 ) {
                if ( window.event ) {
                    // Write back to IE's event object
                    window.event.keyCode = 0;
                }
                sar = true;

                // Trigger custom help here
                window.location.assign("http://www.google.com")

                return false;
            }
        });

    });
```

Here i attached the image of the trigger when i click the Alt button[image]

Comment: It is not possible to disable this shortcut from browser.

Comment: How can we achieve that behaviour

Comment: Select a different shortcut

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works for me in firefox and chrome.

```
$(document).on('keydown', function (evt) {
    if ( evt.keyCode === 18 ) {
            if ( window.event ) {
                // Write back to IE's event object
                window.event.keyCode = 0;
            }
            sar = true;

            // Trigger custom help here
            window.location.assign("http://www.google.com")

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you prasath. its working already but in IE its getting an problem as it going to the target along with the default browser behavior, am in the need of remove that default behavior.

Comment: You should allow blocked content in IE.

Comment: bro its wrking in IE also but the image what i attached in the post have u noticed that it will go to the target and also its triggering the File event in the browser menu. I want that to be blocked, how to do that

Comment: @Prasath The questioner want du disable functionality from browser (if the alt key is pressed, don't show the hidden browser menue).

Comment: @reporter I got the question clearly. I am looking to solve the issue.